# Unity3d project crashes VSCode

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

Medium-size Unity3d project. Opens fine in VSCode on OS X, opening it in VSCode on Windows results in deep freeze (and crash).

What I found so far:
Unity3d creates .csproj files with target .Net framework "v2.0". Target persists between development environments.
OmniSharp logs lots of warnings like:

```
[WARNING:OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem] The primary reference "System.Xml.Linq" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Xml.Linq" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
```

Manually switching target framework to "v3.5" in .csproj files resolves warnings and avoids VSCode freeze, but as soon as I add new file to project Unity regenerates .csproj files.

Any ideas why it works on Mac, but refuses to work (without modifications) on Windows?

Comment: Suggest to report this as bug report over at https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Turns out it was integration plugin that switched target framework to "v2.0" from Unity's default (and working) "v3.5".

Pull request submitted :)